# TinyMCE remove item from context menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce, contextmenu

Can any one please let me know how we can remove items from a TinyMCE ContextMenu. I.e., normal Cut, Copy, Paste items?

I've seen several references to add items to the context menu shown inside the editor, but not for removing the same.

Please help :)-

Answer (score 0):

When you initiate TinyMCE, you can explicitly state which buttons to include:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : ""
});
```

(example taken from the [docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3atheme_advanced_buttons_1_n))

**Edit**

Sorry, the question is about the Context Menu (a.k.a the right-click menu).

Have you tried [this plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3acontextmenu) which lets you do this?:

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "contextmenu",
    contextmenu: "link image inserttable | cell row column deletetable"
});
```

Comment: This is about the customization of the editor GUI. I'm asking about removing default items from context menu of the editor.

Comment: benjaminjosephw: Nope. That one removes the context menu and not the items in context menu. Thanks :)-